# A php button cant call a function on click

Tags: javascript, php

I just want to create a button that when I click on it, it will read a text file I have in the same directory as this php file.
I create this code but when I click at ethe button nothing happens.. Did I make something wrong? Can someone help me because I a beginner at php and javascript.
Thanks,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<button onclick="read()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function read(){
  
$myfile = fopen("lala.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("lala.txt"));
fclose($myfile);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use PHP functions in the javascript `<script>` tag.

Comment: There is no `fopen()` in javascript. You are confusing javascript with PHP

Comment: Replace `<script>...</script>` with `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: @mickdev again happens nothiong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: I didn't check the validity of your code. I just pointed out that you are using php function between javascript tags without no reason

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read using click in javascript, you can use AJAX like this

index.html

```
<html>
<title>Your Page</title>
<script>
function load()
{
    var xmlHttpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");            
    }

    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("ajaxInfo").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "ajax_file.txt",true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajaxInfo"> </div>
<button type="button" onclick="load()">Go!</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

and some text file like ajax_file.txt

```
Your file to read here, everything
```

Comment: Ok. Reallu helpful. And if I want to check for an attribute inside this file if it is true or false how do I do that?F.ex inside the file I read exists an attribute x. I want to check if it is true or false.

Comment: better way to achieve what you want is parse it first in another php file before getting it to load to you own page so you don't have to check any... What are you planning on making?

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript and PHP are two different things.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

As far as my JavaScript knowledge goes, you can't read files directly from your file system with standard JavaScript. If you're using NodeJS, then you can because it extends standard JS.
The only way of reading a file in JS is to make a `GET` request to the file:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "relative/path/to/file.txt", false);
xhr.send()
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

This will request the file on your server synchronously (blocking request) and log its contents to the JavaScript console.